# sort an xml file based on a content within a tag

Tags: xml, awk, sed

Following is my input file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" <id>2301</id></InputRecord>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" <id>2000</id></InputRecord>
```

When I sort this by id tag, I want the output file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" <id>2000</id></InputRecord>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" <id>2301</id></InputRecord>
```

Currently am using a multi-step process :
1.Have a file which has just the id in it.add line numbers to each line
2.Take my input file and add line numbers to each line
3.Join both files based on line number and create a new input file
4.Sort the new input file and get rid of the additional appid in the front.

This is too tedious if I have to do this for every file that I need to sort.

I need some help on sorting the input file in just one step. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the file on the second field using `>` as the delimiter:

```
sort -t'>' -nk2,2 file
```

Comment: why do i need to use a nk2,2? Is it not enough if I just use a nk2?

Comment: For your data `nk2` would suffice.

Comment: Hi @sudo_O: this gets complicated if I add more tags in the input line. Sample input line is                                          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Input xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><tagA><tagB>1</tagB><tagC>10</tagC><tagD>1234567891011213</tagD><tagE>ABC</tagE></tagA></Input> ; I want to sort by tagD. I increased nk to the respective filed number.. but the output is not as expected. It seems to have sorted in some random order

Comment: I can not comment on why it doesn't not work, you have not provided enough information.  Why have unaccepted this answer!?

Comment: Guess it happened by mistake.I have accepted it again.The answer that you provided works very well for my initial i/p.Thanks!When my i/p has more tags,it is not working and any help is appreciated.Here is my sample i/p again(am not able to format it in the comments section.Hope you can see it right within double quotes."<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" <tagA><tagB>1</tagB><tagC>10</tagC><tagD>23015678910</tagD></tagA></InputRecord>".I want to sort it by tagD contents. so I gave nk as 7.But it is not sorting as expected.

Comment: There are only 7 closing tags in the sample row but isn't one missing from `<InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";` so it should be 8? Don't paste date into a comment add it to the question and format it properly. One row isn't particularly useful either as by definition it is already sorted.

Comment: Corrected the tag error. My input has the correct sets of opening and closign tags. I also gave one line sample cos comments have restricted number of characters. "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><InputRecord xmlns:xsi= "w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";> <tagA><tagB>1</tagB><tagC>10</tagC><tagD>23015678910</tagD></tagA></InputRecord>‌​". Please assume that the 2nd line is almost the same expect for varying numbers between each tag. Even if nk is correct, the sorting order is not right